# IntelliJ IDEA methods parameters not displaying correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, autocomplete, javadoc

I'd begin with an image, which shows what I'm trying to tell.
Here I'm comparing the `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3` hints with the `Eclipse 4.7.2` ones.

[image]
The project I set up is composed of a set of libraries, with their corresponding JavaDocs.
The same is done on Eclipse.

[image]

[image]
How do I display the correct naming using IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently IntelliJ IDEA does not take parameter names from javadoc, so given a java library with no sources and compiled with no debug information, it takes parameter names from compiled code. Please vote for this request: [IDEA-125988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125988).

Comment: Hi Andrey. I'm not an expert on the IntelliJ Platform, but would a plug-in/extension help on this matter?

Comment: I think it is possible to implement a plugin for this. E.g. View | Parameter Info action is provided via [ParameterInfoHandler](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-d00d8b4ae3ed33097972b8a4286b336bf4ffcfab/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/lang/parameterInfo/ParameterInfoHandler.java) (`codeInsight.parameterInfo` extension point).